# PhantomJS for Flask application

Tags: python, selenium, flask, phantomjs, putty

The first I did, was getting in my puTTY and installing flask and apache2 following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-flask-application-on-an-ubuntu-vps) guide over here. Everything went smoothly, commands did what they had to do and it raised 0 problems. Until here, fine.

Then, in order to complete my application, I needed 2 things: phantomJS() and selenium. When I want to install selenium, I write the command

> sudo apt-get install selenium

then I run

> selenium

to make sure it's indeed running. Then when I import selenium in my code, it no longer gives me a server error, which is great.

I installed then phantomjs with the command

> sudo apt-get install phantomjs

Previously, I had an error when I typed

> phantomjs

But now I no longer do, phantomjs it getting recognized and not giving errors.
However, when I try to load my form with the post method, it doesn't do anything as it did in localhost.
In localhost, when I sent some info over POST method, a new window browser would load in the background thanks to phantomjs, would extract some keywords and display them in a new table.

However, when I do the same from the server, it doesn't show no errors but also it doesn't do nothing. It loads a bit (a milisecond) and stops, without giving errors or doing what's supposed to do.

The code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for, redirect, flash, session
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver

nombres = []

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "a super secret key"

@app.route('/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def homepage():
    error=None
    try: 
        if request.method == 'POST':
            name = request.form['name']
            city = request.form['city']

            #browser = webdriver.Firefox()
            browser = webdriver.phantomjs()
            browser.set_window_size(1120, 550)
            browser.implicitly_wait(10)
            browser.get('thewebpagehere') #this is on purpose, changed

            browser.quit()

            return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
        elif request.method == 'GET':
            return render_template("main.html")

    except Exception as e:
        flash(e)

@app.route('/dashboard/')
def dashboard():
    return render_template("dashboard.html", nombres=nombres)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

I removed a lot of code that came after the browser loaded, for space purposes, but basically it's just code that scraped the site. With that code or without it, it's still not even opening a hidden browser with phantomjs and I'm not sure why.

Should I do something different? Please feel free to tell me if my post needs something else (I know error handling looks horrific, I'm not worried about that right now), or you need additional information, i've been with this for a week and I can't find answers from anyone.

Thanks for your time.

EDIT: i'm a bit dumb